# Do I need cudaSetDevice before cudaStreamSynchronize?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

In my system I program multiple GPUs concurrently. Do I need to call `cudaSetDevice()` before calling `cudaStreamSynchronize()`?

When creating the `cudaStream_t` objects, I did set the device correctly before calling `cudaStreamCreate()`.

Comment: Events and streams can be synchronized against even if the current device is not the device associated with the stream -- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-and-event-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think you need to call the function `cudaSetDevice()` again if you already used it when creating the stream.

Resources:

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-always-set-current-device-avoid-multithreading-bugs/

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-many-times-does-cudasetdevice-need-to-be-called/10646